# EnterpriseDT - How to disable ssh keyboard-interactive authentication?

Tags: authentication, ssh, ftp, sftp, enterprisedt

I'm using EnterpriseDT library to connect to a sFTP server.

When I try a username and password (Password Authentication), after the first atempt failed, it starts trying keyboard-interactive authentication, prompting for a password.

Is it possible to disable keyboard-interactive authentication?

Here's what's happening:

1. Password authentication
2. Waiting for packet
3. Packet arrived
4. Auth partial success. Try: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
5. Keyboard interactive authentication
6. Waiting for packet
7. Packet arrived
8. Prompt: Password:
9. Waiting for packet
10. Packet arrived
11. Auth partial success. Try: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
12. Waiting for packet
13. Packet arrived
14. Prompt: Password:
15. Loop (9 to 15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Library bug fixed in version 8.6.1 (23 Sep 2014).